# how to create a attribute programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, php-7

I need to delete the existing attribute called Manufacturer if this attribute exists.

And then Create a new attribute called Manufacturer with the same properties as that of the existing one.its created programatically while installing the module.

And how to give the option value for this attribute from custom table .

How to do this in magento2.

Thanks.

**Update:**

```
<?php
namespace XXX\Manufacturer\Model\Config\Source;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    public $manufacturer;
    public function __construct(
        \XXX\Manufacturer\Model\ResourceModel\Manufacturer\Collection $manufacturer
    ) {
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {

        // $this->_options = [ ['label' => __('Test'), 'value'=>'0'] ];
        if (null === $this->_options) {
            foreach($this->manufacturer as $manufacturer) {
                $this->_options[] = [
                    'label' => $manufacturer->getName(),
                    'value' =>  $manufacturer->getId()
                ];
            }
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the attrbute add below code in your module `UpgradeData.php`

```
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
 'your_attribute_code');
```

You will need to add source model to render data from custom model here's the sample code to add dropdown attribute:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'your_attribute_code',
    [
        'group' => 'General',
        'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Product Attribute Label',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => '1',
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
    ]
);
```

Create `Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Source/Options.php` file and add below code:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    public $manufacturer;
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Manufacturer\Collection $manufacturer
    ) {
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {

        // $this->_options = [ ['label' => __('Test'), 'value'=>'0'] ];
        $arr = [];
        if (null === $this->_options) {
            foreach($this->manufacturer as $manufacturer) {
                $arr[] = [
                    'label' => __($manufacturer->getName()),
                    'value' =>  $manufacturer->getId()
                ];
            }
            $this->_options = $arr;
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Hope This Help!

Comment: updated my post

Comment: @ManoM I have updated my answer please review. Please accept as answer so it will helpful to others.

Comment: It does not get option value from custom table ?

Comment: load your custom model in Options.php and set the array in $this->_options.

Comment: update my code .......

Comment: Check i have updated my code.

Comment: i have put exit in public function getAllOptions()
    {echo "hi";exit; not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90317/discussion-between-ashish-viradiya-and-mano-m).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `Magento\Eav\Model\Config` object and use the `getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributecode)` function to check if your custom eav attribute with code `$attributecode` already exist or not.

**Before Create Attribute Check Attribute Already Exist Or Not If Exit Then Remove Attribute**

> ```
> $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode);
> if (!$attribute || !$attribute->getAttributeId()) 
> {
>     $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'my_attribute');
> }
>
> $eavSetup->addAttribute(
>                 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
>                 'your_attribute',
>                 [
>                     'group' => 'General',
>                     'type' => 'int',
>                     'backend' => '',
>                     'frontend' => '',
>                     'label' => 'Attribute_Label',
>                     'input' => 'boolean',
>                     'class' => '',
>                     'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
>                     'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
>                     'visible' => true,
>                     'required' => false,
>                     'user_defined' => false,
>                     'default' => '1',
>                     'apply_to' => ''
>                 ]
>             );
> ```

Comment: updated my post